# Where does webpack place its output for webpack dev server to use?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I see in the output directory of the manifest json that states what files were produced by my webpack, but I'm curious where are those files actually located? Where does webpack dev server go to locate these files and then serve them?

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1141

Answer (score 2):

`webpack-dev-server` runs in memory so the files are not available for the user. However, they implemented a feature to write the files to disk in the [version 3.1.10](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/releases/tag/v3.1.10) by adding `writeToDisk` option to your webpack configuration object

```
devServer: {
  writeToDisk: true
}
```

You could also use `webpack --watch` command to serve files from your build directory.